# Where are Anaconda's libraries for PYTHONPATH?

Tags: macos, python, path

I installed Anaconda's graphical installer successfully. I configured it to Python 3.5 by

```
conda create -n py35 python=3.5
source activate py35 % to deactive source deactivate
conda install notebook ipykernel
ipython kernel install --user
```

### With PYTHONPATH

I want to get Anaconda's libraries in PYTHONPATH. 
They are not located in `$HOME/.anaconda/lib/python3.5/site-packages`. 
Here is a similar [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/q/18567472/54964) without an answer about *PYTHONPATH problems in OSX*. 
I run by accident `pip install conda` just to test if you can confuse the system by installing second Anaconda, but you cannot and you get

```
Requirement already satisfied (use --upgrade to upgrade): conda in /Users/masi/anaconda/lib/python3.5/site-packages
```

where you apparently see the location of the libraries of Anaconda. 
My `$HOME/.bash_profile`

```
export PYTHONPATH=/Users/masi/anaconda/lib/python3.5/site-packages

# otherwise PYTHONPATH fails in OS X; see history for logs
export LC_ALL=en_US.UTF-8
export LANG=en_US.UTF-8
```

I run my test code

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
%matplotlib inline
```

and I get unsuccessfully

```
/Users/masi/anaconda/lib/python3.5/site-packages/matplotlib/font_manager.py:273: UserWarning: Matplotlib is building the font cache using fc-list. This may take a moment.
  warnings.warn('Matplotlib is building the font cache using fc-list. This may take a moment.')
```

I do not know where Matplotlib keeps its cache. In Linux, removal with `rm -rf ~/.cache/matplotlib` would be possible but not in OS X. 
This can be a bug in Matplotlib that has not been solved in OS X. I sent a message to the thread about the issue in the project's Github [here](https://github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib/issues/5836).
The cache directory is empty, `ls -a $HOME/.matplotlib/` gives empty list where you find the cache directory by `import matplotlib; matplotlib.get_cachedir()` in ipython.

### Without PYTHONPATH

My PATH is

```
/Users/masi/anaconda/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/Library/TeX/texbin
```

I install numpy by `sudo -H pip install numpy`. I run the test code but I get

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ImportError                               Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-1-a38059fd5ca4> in <module>()
----> 1 import numpy as np
      2 import pandas as pd
      3 import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
      4 get_ipython().magic('matplotlib inline')

ImportError: No module named 'numpy'
```

so something wrong with pip in installing the modules. 
I have both `conda` via `pip` and Anaconda. 
This may not be optimal. Please, propose different setting.

### Trying to get rid of conda

I run `pip uninstall conda` but I still get the error about missing `numpy` although I installed it with `pip`. I think have some PATH problem. How can you uninstall all packages installed by conda?

---

How can you add Anaconda's Python Libraries in PYTHONPATH?

Comment: probably bestt to run without any PYTHONPATH the anaconda setup should just work. Run in a virtual path by using conda activate

Comment: What is your path and do you have both condo via pip and anaconda?

Comment: I get different errors :( I had to install more than you e.g. condo install matplotlib. Time to get a real VM I think

Comment: @Mark I installed matplotlib by `sudo -H pip install matplotlib`. I am trying to get rid of `conda`. Please, see the body.

Comment: Using sudo etc will mess things up as that is not using anaconda - only use one package manager

Comment: I would use condo install rather than pip conda http://conda.pydata.org/docs/_downloads/conda-pip-virtualenv-translator.html

Comment: Excellent table! What should I do now? Not use `pip`? Use anaconda or conda? Uninstall `pip`-installed packages?

Comment: I have a problem with mkl so cannot provide a working solution

Comment: What is mkl? Can you open a thread about it so we can look at it?

Comment: Could anyone with rep>300 tag this 'anaconda'?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I think one good option is to gave up with Anaconda and use `Canopy` under an academic license (user2738815). 
Another option is to use Debian Linux, where I have not experienced any such problems.